# Why is UI not updating after button click in React?

Tags: reactjs, database, request, react-hooks, state

I'm working on something similar like Youtube like/dislike functionality. First getting result by it's id. Then checking and filtering and lastly doing put request to the database. **But the problem is that 'likes' values in the UI  changes only after page refresh**. I tried using useState hook and manipulate the state when getting response from put request, without succeeding. Everything happens on button click.

*Any advice is strongly appreciated.*

**My States**

```
const [likes, setLikes] = useState([])
const [dislikes, setDislikes] = useState([])
```

**Getting the review**

```
const getDislikedReviewById = (id) => {
    axios.get(`https://landlordstrapi.herokuapp.com/cool-project/${id}`)
    .then((response) => {
handleDislike(response.data)
    })
    .catch(err => {
        console.log(err);
    });
}
```

**Working with functionality**

```
const handleDislike = (data) => {
    const id = data.id
    setDislikes([...data.comment_info.dislikes])
    setLikes([...data.comment_info.likes])
    const userToken = localStorage.getItem('user') || []
    const checkIfLikeExists = likes.find(item => item === userToken)
    const checkIfDislikeExists = dislikes.find(item => item === userToken)
    if(checkIfLikeExists && checkIfLikeExists.length) {
        setLikes(likes.filter(a => a !== userToken))
        setDislikes(dislikes.push(userToken))
    }
    if(!checkIfDislikeExists && !checkIfLikeExists) {
        setDislikes(dislikes.push(userToken))
        }
    JSON.stringify(dislikes)
updateDislikes(data, id, dislikes, likes)
}
```

**When everything is done sending UPDATE request**

```
const updateDislikes = (data, id, dislikes, likes) => {
    axios.put(`https://landlordstrapi.herokuapp.com/cool-project/${id}`, { 
        comment_info: {
            likes: likes,
            dislikes: dislikes,
            comment: data.comment_info.comment
            }
         })
        .then(function(response){
            console.log('saved successfully')
    });
}
```

**My like button**

```
 <Votes>
   <GrLike style={{cursor: "pointer"}} onClick={() => getReviewById(id)}  size={10}/>
      <VoteValue>
                  {likes && likes.length ? likes.length : null}
      </VoteValue>
 </Votes>
```

Comment: Be aware, React JS batches state updates in a single handler. This means that in your `handleDislike` function, there is no guarantee that when you call `setLikes(...)` that `likes` will have the latest data.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you want to update the state or set the data returned by the api. I assumed now you would like to set the data from the api. If you want to set the state you can do so by using the old state, so pass a function to the setState call

```js
setDislikes((oldDislikes) => [...oldDislikes, userToken]);
```

and I would update the handleDislike function as so

```js
const handleDislike = (data) => {
  const {
    id,
    comment_info: { dislikes, likes }
  } = data;

  let newLikes = likes;
  let newDislikes = dislikes;

  const userToken = localStorage.getItem("user") || [];
  const likeExists = likes.find((item) => item === userToken);
  const dislikeExists = dislikes.find((item) => item === userToken);

  if (likeExists) {
    newLikes = newLikes.filter((a) => a !== userToken);
  }
  if ((!dislikeExists && !likeExists) || likeExists) {
    newDislikes = [...dislikes, userToken];
  }

  // set new values
  setDislikes(newDislikes);
  setLikes(newLikes);

  updateDislikes(data, id, newDislikes, newLikes);
};
```

Comment: Sorry for a bad explanation, Julian. My wish is that the data returned from the put request would immediately appear(in this case it is a like count) in the UI. Unfortunately to achieve this, after a button click I have to click refresh... May be that I'm thinking wrong through whole procedure and would appreciate your knowledge. Your code is so much cleaner... Thank you very much!

Comment: Glad I can help. Actually I would assume that this data will be updated in the ui due to the state change. Does it not work?

Comment: There was problem with my main state with reviews. After a put request I forgot to update my state and it didn't rerender. Once again, thank you for response. I copied your code and it's tempting to redo a lot of other code in this project hehe.

Comment: Haha, glad to help :)